# Swift Accessing Values in Dictionary

Tags: ios, swift, dictionary, nested

I have a swift dictionary and I am trying to access my values in my array.

My Dictionary that I make looks like this:

```
["results": {
Democrats =     {
    percent = 67;
    raw = 4;
};
Republicans =     {
    percent = 33;
    raw = 2;
};
"total_answers" = 6;
}, "success": 1]
```

I made another dictionary to get this:

```
let test = dictionary["results"] as! [String : AnyObject] 

["Democrats": {
percent = 67;
raw = 4;
}, "Republicans": {
percent = 33;
raw = 2;
}, "total_answers": 6]
```

I can access values like:

```
let testing = test["total_answers"]
```

I want to access the values for percent and raw for example:

```
Democrats =     {
percent = 67;
raw = 4;
};
```

The percent and raw key are static but the Democrats is a string that will never be the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what notation you're using for your dictionary but it doesn't compile in Swift.

A dictionary with [String:Any] as type would work but manipulating the data is going to be a type casting nightmare.  You should consider using a regular structure where all values have the same type.

For example (using a typealias for the two value tuple):

```
typealias Votes = (percent:Int, raw:Int)

var results = [ "Democrats"  : Votes(percent:67,  raw:4),
                "Repubicans" : Votes(percent:33,  raw:2),
                "Totals"     : Votes(percent:100, raw:6)
              ]

let democratVotes = results["Democrats"]!.raw
```

Answer (score 0):

So here `let democrats:[String : Int] = test["Democrats"] as! [String : Int]` will provide you new dictionary, containing only

```
Democrats =     {
percent = 67;
raw = 4;
};
```